# How To Remove All Text Before a Specific Value in a String

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, line-breaks

I have the following string, "blahblah
hellothere", that I would like to be shortened to "hellothere" using JavaScript and/or JQuery.

I have tried using the following code:

```
var titletext123 = "blahblah<br>hellothere"
        var injuryt3xt = titletext123.substring(titletext123.indexOf("<br>") +1);
```

Which only returns "br>hellothere".

Does anyone have any code which will get rid of the 
 and all text before it?

Thank you very much. All of your help is appreciated!

Comment: You're not accounting for the length of your break tag: `var injuryt3xt = titletext123.substring(titletext123.indexOf("<br>") +4); /* +4 */`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it

```
var titletext123 = "blahblah<br>hellothere" var injuryt3xt = titletext123.substring(titletext123.indexOf("<br>") + 4);
```

So it is +4. Which accounts for all the characters in `<br>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and get second element.

```js
var titletext123 = "blahblah<br>hellothere" ;    
var injuryt3xt = titletext123.split("<br>")[1];
alert(injuryt3xt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expression:

```
var text = "blahblah<br>hellothere"
var clipped = str.replace(/.+\<br\>/, ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option (depending on circumstances) might be:

```
var injuryt3xt = titletext123.split("<br>")[1];
```

Which would split the string on `<br>` and return an array with the left-over parts ... the second of which is referred to with the `[1]`